Restrict hazelcast clients to connect to a hazelcast cluster/instance
I have a hazelcast cluster in which there are two instances running in spring boot java project.
I want to secure this cluster/instances so that no clients will connect to it to access data.
I am using open source edition of hazelcast. How can I achieve this?
One approach is to use different clusternames but this solution doesn't suit my requirement.
Is there any other authentication methods available in open source edition? Please help.

There is no option in open source edition.
You can choose to have different clusternames to achieve this.
